# How do you cut on multiple faces at the same time?

Tags: shrinkwrap

Please go light on me, this is my first time posting and I am just starting Blender this week.

My issue is, is that I am trying to cut a hole in a cylinder. It's an archway that acts as a walkway into the cylinder. However, I need to cut this archway on multiple sides and at various heights. Think colosseum, just smaller and less sophisticated.

I have used the following youtube tutorial up to deleting faces. (Note: To be more clear, I have not deleted any faces yet)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ci1jBOm_5NY

This is what it looks like so far:
[image]

every face that is similar to the one with the arch I need to have an arch on to cut the hole.
I hope I have made sense. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't focus on that you have to cut. I would create one entrance, then repeat that using the array modifier (use and empty that you rotate with) to duplicate it in a circle. Once you have a circle, duplicate it upwards.

Comment: do you have an image of the object you want to achieve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

suppose you have this object, you want to cut:

[image]

1. Add Mesh -> Circle
2. Then hit R -> X -> 90 and move on y axis like so:

[image]

3. Tab for edit mode, go in side view

[image]

4. select bottom half of circle and hit X -> vertices

[image]

[image]

5. select the bottom 2 vertices
6. press E -> Z -> mouse down as you need -> F

[image]

7. Tab
8. move this guy up as you need
9. select this guy, then your object to cut

[image]

10. tab -> A
11. F3 -> Knife project

[image]

12. choose cut through in the left bottom corner
13. choose face select
14. choose x-ray

[image]

15. choose all faces which are inside your cut loop
16. result:

[image]

...but...for each face, this is too much work. So you should try it like Gunslinger said and make one face, cut it out and then use array modifier.

So the better way would be:

1. add cube
2. cut an arch hole in the cube like i described above

[image]

3. delete "inner faces" of the arch

[image]

4. move the result on y axis in edit mode like this

[image]

important: notice, that the center point is still at 0,0 (z value does not matter)

5. add empty

[image]

6. apply rotation to your cube/arch
7. add array modifier to cube/arch like this:

[image]

8. add some rotation z value in empty as you need and adapt count in array as you need ( i used 30 degrees and count 12 )

[image]

...and of course there are more possibilies ... ;)

you could build an arch like this (explanation as above):

[image]

move the arch inside your object

[image]

and then add array modifier like above to arch with empty ...

so you got this:

[image]

then add boolean modifier to your object/cylinder and
set viewport visibility to bounds for your arch

[image]

and you will get

[image]

then add another cylinder like this

[image]

and add second boolean on your object for that cylinder  and set viewport visibility of this cylinder to bounds to get this

[image]

[image]

Comment: OMG! I am going to try the method with the cube! thank you so much.

Comment: you are welcome!

Comment: Okay, I add rotation to the empty and it just spirals out. It does not connect them and make them into a circle.

Comment: Did you apply rotation and scale before?

Comment: If you don’t get it work, upload your blend file and I will help you…but…tomorrow. Here is now 11:29 p.m.

Comment: Okay, for some reason the rotation and scale were not applying because the rotation on the Z-axis was 41 degrees. It is working now. Thank you so much, you kind soul.

Comment: Also, for me to get it to work it, I had to check mark location